# Entity Framework | Composite Primary Keys

Tags: entity-framework, composite-primary-key

I just need to get the Composite primary key of an entity.

my entity:

```
public class UserRole
{
public int ID_User {get;set;}
public int ID_Role {get;set;}
}
```

my entity mapping:

```
public class UserRoleMap: EntityTypeConfiguration<UserRole>
{
// Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => new { t。ID_User, t.ID_Role });

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.ID_User)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            this.Property(t => t.ID_Role)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("User_Role");
            this.Property(t => t.ID_User).HasColumnName("ID_User");
            this.Property(t => t.ID_Role).HasColumnName("ID_Role");
}
```

my goal is to get "ID_User" and "ID_Role".
I really doesn't have idea how to do that...

Thanks.
Regards,
Leona

Comment: It's not clear what the question is, could you try to rephrase it please?

Comment: Hello qujck, I mean I want to get the primary key which are "ID_User" and "ID_Role".

Comment: Do you mean search the database (such as `DbSet.Find`)?